# Kubernetes Random Port

Tags: kubernetes, selenium-webdriver

I have an agent that will expose random ports to be accessed from another deployment/pod.
How can I achieve this on kubernetes? Can we do this?
I've tried with headless service like this

```
 apiVersion: v1
 kind: Service
 metadata:
   name: multilogin-agent-headless
 spec:
   selector:
     app: mulitlogin-agent
   clusterIP: None
```

my deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mulitlogin-agent-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: agent
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: agent
      annotations:
        prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'
        prometheus.io/path: '/metrics'
        prometheus.io/port: '8000'
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: agent
        image: myagent
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 45001
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: ghcr-io-pull-secret
```

I can only connect using to port 45001 that exposed at the deployment manifest, I can't connect to another port in the agent.
here's the detailed process

1. pod a request to agent
2. agent send response with which port will be open ( its random)
3. pod a request to agent:<random_port> random port will be get from step 2

Regards and thanks

Comment: Can you fix the application to listen on a fixed port?  That will work better in the container environment.

Comment: sadly I can't because its from 3rd party.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Nginx's sidecar with a concrete port that you put in the manifest. Then manage the configuration of random ports on Nginx with dynamic config with the help of the init container. But it's better to stick to the port overall on the app's level.

Comment: can you give some documentation link or some reference for me to read to implement what you mean?